# SQL Beginner. Error = "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '4+' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL, using temp tables.  Here is some of the code that is tripping me up.  It doesn't like the '4+'. It wants it to be an int but I need it to say '4+'.

'''

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AB;
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(Base.[Policy Number],8,10) as 'PolicyID'
     , Base.[Policy Number]
     , COUNT(Base.[Claim Number]) as 'ClaimCount'
INTO #AB
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
            [Policy Number]
          , [Claim Number]
       FROM [VRU_DataWarehouse].[Claims].[Claim]) Base
WHERE [Policy Number] LIKE 'VUW%'
GROUP BY Base.[Policy Number]

SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE WHEN #AB.ClaimCount > 3 THEN '4+'
            WHEN #AB.ClaimCount is NULL THEN '0'
            ELSE #AB.ClaimCount END AS 'ClaimHistory'
```

'''

Comment: Your Query is incomplete.. Where are you selecting the distinct from??
I am assuming the newly created temp table #AB

Comment: A case expression's return values must have matching data types. Try `... ELSE cast(#AB.ClaimCount as varchar(11)) END ...`

Comment: "4+" is not a numeric value. If you're intention is denote the positive integer value 4, you should just use "4". If you're intention is to include the "+" for some reason, it cannot be stored as a numeric data type (use a text-based data type instead).

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this error is that `CASE` returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result expressions and the optional `ELSE` result expression, based on the [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). You have integer column `#AB.ClaimCount` and because `int` data type has higher precedence, text data is implicitly converted to integer.

Try with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CASE WHEN #AB.ClaimCount > 3 THEN '4+'
            WHEN #AB.ClaimCount is NULL THEN '0'
            ELSE CONVERT(varchar(11), #AB.ClaimCount) 
       END AS 'ClaimHistory'
```

Comment: Why `varchar(MAX)`?

Comment: @Larnu, I agree, `varchar(11)` will be enough, based on the length of `ClaimCount`.